# How to enter fullscreen from an inner component using react-full-screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fullscreen

I currently have a wrapper `Fullscreen` component that requires a `handle` property from `'react-full-screen'` library. I'm trying to reference that handle property from an inner child component but It's not working. Is there clever way to achieve this functionality. Here's what I got so far [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-rain-tkmjoc?file=/src/InnerComponent.tsx:0-381) and I'm open to other fullscreen solutions.

App.tsx:

```
import FullScreenListener from "./FullScreenListener";
import InnerComponent from "./InnerComponent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FullScreenListener>
        <InnerComponent />
      </FullScreenListener>
    </div>
  );
}
```

FullScreenListener.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFullScreenHandle, FullScreen } from "react-full-screen";

interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const FullScreenListener = ({ children }: IProps) => {
  const handle = useFullScreenHandle();
  return (
    <>
      <FullScreen handle={handle}>{children}</FullScreen>
    </>
  );
};

export default FullScreenListener;
```

InnerComponent.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFullScreenHandle } from "react-full-screen";

const InnerComponent = () => {
  const handle = useFullScreenHandle();

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("click, go full screen!");
    handle.enter();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go fullscreen</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default InnerComponent;
```